# Rails bad array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes, controller

I generated an array attribute using

```
rails gen ... AddTaglistToPictures taglist:array
```

In my create function in my Pictures controller, in if @picture.save , i have

```
tagList =[]
tags = @picture.tags
tags.each do |tag|
  tagList += [tag.tagcontent]
end
@picture.taglist = tagList
@picture.save
```

In the above, i have Tag as model, built with nested_form gem (I need a model as well as the list)

When i make a group of tags, i get a list like this

```
"---\n- table\n- kevin\n- table\n- kevin\n"
```

these are the right tags but they aren't really useable (because trying to pull out elements is like tag[0] is '-', tag[4] is 'n'.) How do i make this attribute so it formats the array properly

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store an array in a column you need to use the serialize keyword

```
class Photo
   serialize :tags, Array
end
```

then add a tags column to Photo class of type string (or text if there will be many)

Answer (score 1):

`"---\n- table\n- kevin\n- table\n- kevin\n"` is a serialized yaml array.

Try loading it with `YAML.load("---\n- table\n- kevin\n- table\n- kevin\n")`. That should give you a proper ruby array.

Comment: your answer sort of works, it wont take just pic.taglist = YAML.load(pic.taglist). how do i change the actual array so i can pass it as a regular array through a AJAX call into javascript

Comment: Does that comment make sense (I mean i cant just do YAML.load(pic.taglist) in javascript )

Comment: You can convert the array to json if you want to pass it to javascript.

Comment: How can i do that, i tried something simple like pic.taglist.to_json which gives me "\"---\\n- table\\n- kevin\\n- table\\n- kevin\\n\"" , I also ... nevermind, how do i do that. sorry if that sounds kind of dumb, but i don't know how to output the taglist as json (within my Picture json array which was made automatically)

Comment: Oh, yeah, you'd have to convert it from a serialized YAML object first, which would make the code a bit messier (`YAML.load(pic.taglist).to_json`).

Comment: Regardless, CambridgeMike's answer is better than mine, go for that one.

Answer (score 1):

In fairness, you did tell it to use an array, so it's going to serialize an actual array.

IMO this should be a normal association:

```
class Photo
    has_many :tags
end
```

Or you could just use [`acts_as_taggable_on_steroids`](https://github.com/jviney/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids) or any of the tagging plugins.